# How do i use SnackBar in onPostExecute method in AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-snackbar

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>  {

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    textView.setText(result);
    button.setEnabled(true);

    progressDialog.hide();

    Snackbar snackbar;
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(/*what would i use here*/,"Download Complete", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use textview in Snackbar.make(textview,"Download Complete",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

Comment: You've to add the view

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-snackbar-example/

Comment: Make public to snackbar parameters once.

Comment: is async class in different file

Comment: @Pzy64 That actually doesn't matter in java.

Comment: btw you should not have a non-static inner `AsyncTask` inside an `Activity`. This is a memory leak : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0

Answer (score 2):

You need a `rootView` in your class.

```
private View rootView;
```

You pass this `rootView` as an argument in your constructor.

```
public MyTask(View rootView) {

    this.rootView = rootView;

}
```

In your calling activity you need to pass a `rootView`. This can be any `View`, in a fragment it is usually already called `rootView` and otherwise you would just put your parent layout.

```
new AsyncTask(rootView).execute(); // execute() for starting your AsyncTask
```

Then in your `postExecute()` you can use that `rootView` like this:

```
Snackbar.make(rootView, "a text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Whole code for your case:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>  {

    private View rootView;

    public MyTask(View rootView) {

        this.rootView = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        textView.setText(result);
        button.setEnabled(true);

        progressDialog.hide();

        Snackbar snackbar;
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Download Complete", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `Snackbar.make()` is the layout in which you need to display the snack bar. Normally everyone uses the parent layout of the activity or fragment for this, such as to display the snackbar at the bottom of the screen.

What you should do is create an object of the parent layout of the screen in which you want to display the snackbar and provide it as the first argument.

Comment: He wanted to know how to get it. I provided it in my answer actually.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give an id to the base layout. Here is my main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layoutxx"
tools:context="pzy64.aaa.MainActivity">
```

I gave the id as layoutxx

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConstraintLayout layout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutxx);
    new Test().execute();

}
class Test extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>    {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Snackbar.make(layout,"Hello",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

If AsyncTask is on a different file you may need to pass the view through the constructor. In this case You don't need to pass it through constructor.